# Blender adding image / texture on object does not show up in .obj document

Tags: texturing, uv, image

I've watched some tutorials on how to add images to an object in blender. There are different ways to do it but I choose to do it as the following: with UV image editor and making a material and after that a texture for the image.

This is how it looks in blender as rendered, the front and back view: [image: blender rendered front]
[image: blender rendered back]

I need this blender project to be exported to a .obj file so I can use it for an AR project in ENTiTi, but no matter what I Do, the rectangle will be empty when exported to .obj

[image: object exported]

Material and texture preview:
[image: preview1]
[image: preview2]

Can you guys please help me because I can't find a solution on google or youtube. **I made a **google drive directory** with the blender file, .obj file and the images: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WdspdKiK28vTmJVepi_FWb4Avs1pZOw5?usp=sharing**

Thanks a lot !